# Place Autocomplete API return null in flutter web but works fine in postman

Tags: flutter, google-api, autocomplete, response, google-places-autocomplete

I am using Google Place Autocomplete API for location search And it was working fine in Postman and browser. But when I try to hit it from the flutter application, The response is null. I am not sure what I am missing can anyone help.

NOTE:
It works fine in Android.The NULL issue only happens in flutter web.

**Restriction:** NONE

**No. of Application used:** 2

**Code:**

```
Future<void> fetchingLocationPrediction(String location) async {
  Response response = await GetConnect()
      .get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$location&key=$kGoogleApiKey");
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    if (response.body["status"] == "OK") {
      LocationPredictionModel prediction = LocationPredictionModel.fromJson(response.body);
      print(response.body);
      print(response.statusCode);
    } else {
      print("Something Went Wrong: $location");
      print(response.body);
      print(response.statusCode);
      print("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$location&key=$kGoogleApiKey");
    }
  } else {
    print("Something Went Wrong: $location");
    print(response.body);
    print(response.statusCode);
    print("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$location&key=$kGoogleApiKey");
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to URL encode the input search term?

Comment: can you share your LocationPredictionModel?

Comment: I Think my question is bit confusing. The response itself is NULL. Not the value returned by the function. I have edit my question. The `LocationPrediction` is Just a Model Class.